# How-to test devise with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just wondering, how to test devise's controller with rspec?

With devise, we hand off most of users controller's action to devise, and maybe only a show action for users, and I write the user#show spec in `spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb`, but what about the other actions supplied by devise, how to test them?

or, I just don't need to test the devise controller, 'cause it is been tested while develop the gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would not test devise itself. That's the responsibility of the author of that gem. What I would focus on is the behavior of your application instead. Isolate the devise code by mock/stub where necessary and only test your side of the points where your code intersects with the devise code.

That's not to say you can't write a few quick tests on critical behavior--log in for example.

You might consider reading [The Rspec Book](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book). I found it invaluable to getting my head into the BDD & Rspec mindset.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like some examples, check out the source code in
[Rails 3.1 with Devise and RSpec and Cucumber](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-devise-rspec-cucumber/wiki/Tutorial)